# Connectionstring for windowsServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, windows-server-2012

I have to create windows application with C#.

I have using this connection string:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
                   "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDBname;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                    );
```

Every thing is good,but when I have to copy "debug folder" to the server(and restore DB to the server), my Connectionstring doesn't work.

By the way, both of SQL in client side or Server side doesn't need username and password.

Comment: What do you mean _doesn't work_? You get any error or exception message when you try to connect?

Comment: Using Integrated Security means that the database connection is going to be made in the context of the current user. Running locally, that's probably you. On the server, that depends on a bunch of factors - is this an ASP.NET app? A windows service? WCF service? Give us some more information so that we can help you.

Comment: It's windows Form Application, and didn't connect to the server.

Comment: What's the error message that you have been ?

Comment: OK. Has access to the SQL database been granted to the user who is logging on to the server and running the application? If not, grant access to the user or a group that includes the users who will run the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead of hardcoding the connection string. That way you can make sure you always get a properly formatted connection string.

Second idea: Is the SQL Server instance name also valid for the server? `(local)` identifies the locally running SQL Server instance without and instance name. As soon as your server has an instance name, like for example `SQL2012`, you need to use `local\SQL2012`.

When connecting your SQL Server Management Studio to the server's database, which name do you use there? Does the user your application runs under on the server actually have the rights to access the server and the database?